# How to run libcamera-still in python trough crontab?

Tags: python, camera, cron, libcamera

I'm trying to make a time lapse using `crontab` to manage time intervals. The camera I use is an arducam Autofocus imx519. The `libcamera-still` command works normally when run via terminal. But when I run the following script via `crontab` the line containing `libcamera-still` is not executed.

Here my python script with privileges `u+x`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import subprocess
from pijuice import PiJuice

pj = PiJuice(1,0x14)

# Get battery level and write statement to log
batteryLevel = pj.status.GetChargeLevel()
os.system("date=$(date); text=$(echo '    PICTURE    " + str(batteryLevel) + "'); echo $date$text >> ~/log")

# Get date and separate day and time
date = subprocess.getoutput("date +%F")
time = subprocess.getoutput("date +%H:%M")

# Take picture
out = os.system("libcamera-still -o ~/Pictures/"+date+"/"+time+".jpg --autofocus >> test.txt")
os.system("echo '" + str(out) + "' >> test.txt")
```

and my `crontab` for testing looks like this:

```
* * * * * ./script.py
```

The script is running, the logs are taken correctly, but the line containing `libcamera-still` is not running (no output written to `test.txt`).
The line `os.system("echo '" + str(out) + "' >> test.txt")` always writes `32512` (and I don't know for what it stands for).

When I run the script via terminal ( `$ ./script.py` ) it works perfectly, it writes 0 to `test.txt` and returns the following lines:

```bsh
Preview window unavailable
[11:47:51.665744000] [1201]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0
[11:47:51.715527000] [1212]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:141 No static properties available for 'imx519'
[11:47:51.716860000] [1212]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:143 Please consider updating the camera sensor properties database
[11:47:51.718001000] [1212] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:551 'imx519 10-001a': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[11:47:51.852132000] [1212]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1233 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[11:47:51.856864000] [1212] ERROR DelayedControls delayed_controls.cpp:87 Delay request for control id 0x009a090a but control is not exposed by device /dev/v4l-subdev0
[11:47:51.861199000] [1212]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1356 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx519@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[11:47:51.866415000] [1201]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 2328x1748-YUV420
[11:47:51.871248000] [1212]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:751 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx519@1a - Selected sensor format: 2328x1748-SRGGB10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 2328x1748-pRAA
[11:47:51.983735000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AfTrigger = 1
[11:47:51.985183000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[11:47:51.986450000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[11:47:51.987372000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[11:47:51.989790000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[11:47:51.991590000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[11:47:51.993349000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[11:47:51.994819000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[11:47:51.995729000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 33333, 33333 ]
[11:47:51.996677000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[11:47:52.000276000] [1219]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 3
[11:47:57.258585000] [1201]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 4656x3496-YUV420 (1) 4656x3496-SRGGB10_CSI2P
[11:47:57.267650000] [1212]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:751 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx519@1a - Selected sensor format: 4656x3496-SRGGB10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 4656x3496-pRAA
[11:47:57.505010000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AfTrigger = 1
[11:47:57.506463000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[11:47:57.507638000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[11:47:57.508547000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[11:47:57.511001000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[11:47:57.513578000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[11:47:57.516040000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[11:47:57.517747000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[11:47:57.519464000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 100, 1000000000 ]
[11:47:57.520646000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[11:47:57.520991000] [1229]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:666 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 2
Still capture image received
```

I already tried to change the paths of the command in `crontab` unsuccessfully.
I also tried to run `os.system("cd /home/pi && libcamera-still ...")` with no success.

Any hints or ideas where the problem could be or how can I fix it?
Many thanks in advance for you possible answer!!

Comment: Why not manage the time intervals in your Python code - much easier?

Comment: I tought but I can't do like you said because the power source is a battery and solar cell: if by bad luck the battery dries out it is much harder to make everything work again correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was really siple:
First run via terminal `which libcamera-still`
I got: `/usr/local/bin/libcamera-still`
Then write `os.system("/usr/local/bin/libcamera-still ...")` instead of `os.system("libcamera-still ...")`.

Works like a charm